# How to make a post request with multiple parameters

Tags: rest, go

How could I make a POST request to take in multiple parameters and output info on a webpage, in Go using the standard library.

i.e

user puts in name and favorite hobby

**Name** :

**Hobby** :

**Submit** (button)

then webpage updates and shows

Your Name is **(Name)** and you like to **(Hobby)**

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package in the Go standard library.

The basic process here is:

1. Write a template (in go/HTML template language)
2. Read in the template (using `template.ParseFiles` or similar)
3. Listen for requests
4. Pass information from relevant requests to your template (using `ExecuteTemplate` or similar)

You can pass a struct to `ExecuteTemplate`, which is then accessible in the template you define (see below for an example). For example, if your struct has a field called `Name`, then you can access this information in the template with `{{ .Name }}`.

Here is a sample:

**main.go**:

package main

```
import (
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    // Read your template(s) into the program
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.gohtml"))
}

func main() {
    // Set up routes
    http.HandleFunc("/endpoint", EndpointHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

// define the expected structure of payloads
type Payload struct {
    Name string     `json:"name"`
    Hobby string    `json:"hobby"`
}

func EndpointHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Read the body from the request into a Payload struct
    var payload Payload
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&payload)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Pass payload as the data to give to index.gohtml and write to your ResponseWriter
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", payload)
}
```

**index.gohtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span>Your name is</span><span>{{ .Name }}</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>Your hobby is</span><span>{{ .Hobby }}</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample:

With payload:

```
{
    "name": "Ahmed",
    "hobby": "devving"
}
```

Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span>Your name is</span>
            <span>Ahmed</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Your hobby is</span>
            <span>devving</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note this is pretty fragile, so you should definitely add better error and edge-case handling, but hopefully this is a helpful starting point.